# Can't select or filter data after pivot table in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple Pivot table:

```
WITH relevantData AS (
    SELECT "headline", "entityId", "keyId", "eventType" FROM events
),

model AS (    
    SELECT * 
    FROM relevantData PIVOT(
        MAX("entityId") FOR "eventType" IN ('Buyer', 'Seller')
    ) pvt ("headline", "keyId", "Buyer", "Seller")
)

SELECT * FROM model
```

And the above works, giving me a table of the form

| "headline" | "keyId" | "Buyer" | "Seller" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A Buys B | 4 | A | B |

However, if I try and add a `WHERE "Buyer" = 'A'` at the very end I get an invalid identifier error.

Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The column name has to be wrapped with `"` becauase `"` is part of the identifier:

[image]

The `WHERE` condition:

```
"Buyer" = 'A'
=>
"""Buyer""" = 'A'
```

Query:

```
WITH relevantData AS (
    SELECT "headline", "entityId", "keyId", "eventType" FROM events
),model AS (    
    SELECT * 
    FROM relevantData PIVOT(
        MAX("entityId") FOR "eventType" IN ('Buyer', 'Seller')
    ) pvt ("headline", "keyId", "Buyer", "Seller")
)

SELECT * FROM model
WHERE """Buyer""" = 'A';
```

Output:

[image]

---

Alternatively, moving the column list on the cte level:

```
WITH relevantData AS (
    SELECT "headline", "entityId", "keyId", "eventType" FROM events
),model("headline", "keyId", "Buyer", "Seller") AS (    
    SELECT *
    FROM relevantData PIVOT(
        MAX("entityId") FOR "eventType" IN ('Buyer', 'Seller')
    ) pvt 
)
SELECT *
FROM model
WHERE "Buyer" = 'A';
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE events
AS
SELECT 'A' AS "headline", 'A' AS "entityId", 'A' AS "keyId", 'Buyer'"eventType";
```

Output:

[image]